# Conditional check in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying below code but it's not working as expected. I wanted to check if the cell Value has India or UnitedStatedofAmerica or Germany or Switzerland then go inside and if it's `undefined`, `null` or blank, or it doesn't contain the text location then go to `else` and  set the value to `ROW`, But its not working.

So each time it give me results ROW even if cell have India or UnitedStatedofAmerica and when its null it goes inside the true condition and throw error for split as cell.Value is null

3 Example cell.Value

"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting;Location **India**, Mumbai;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"

"Location **India**;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"

"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingLorem Ipsum is;Location **United Stated of America**; simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"

```js
if (cell.Value.split('Location')[1].split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, "") === "India" || cell.Value.split('Location')[1].split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, "") === "Germany" || cell.Value.split('Location')[1].split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, "") === "UnitedStatesofAmerica" || cell.Value.split('Location')[1].split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, "") === "Switzerland" || cell.Value !== 'undefined' || cell.Value !== null || cell.Value !== "" || cell.Value.toLowerCase().indexOf("Location") !== -1) {
  persona.country = cell.Value.split('Location')[1].split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, "");
} else {
  persona.country = "ROW"
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  "It's not working" doesn't tell us anything, for all we know your data may simply not be what you assume it is.  This is also a good time for you to do some debugging.  There are *a lot* of operations being performed in that condition.  You could extract them into their own variables and check the values of those variables to see if each of those operations does what you expect.

Comment: please add some examples of `cell.Value`.

Comment: @NinaScholz added few example

Comment: btw a to lower cased string can never contain an uppercase letter like `'Location'`. what is this (later comparison) doing?

Comment: there are some cell.Value where i dont have Location field so for that as well it should show ROW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify some parts with some variables and an array of wanted countries.

```js
const
    value = cell.Value || '',
    country = value.split('Location')?.[1]?.split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, ""),
    countries = ["India", "Germany", "UnitedStatesofAmerica", "Switzerland"];

persona.country = countries.includes(country)
    ? country
    : "ROW";
```

Comment: it do work when countries for array and for other countries but there are case where cell.Value is null or cell.Value does not have Location

Comment: what should happen if `null` (not a string) or not having `location`?

Comment: if its null or not having Location then as well it should set value ROW

Answer (score 0):

If `cell.Value` is `null` or `undefined` then calling `.split` will throw an error. You could just add a falsy check for `cell.Value` at the beginning of the to`if` statement.

```
if(cell.Value && cell.Value.split...
```